# How to deal with DBNull in DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have the following C# code

```
 using System.Runtime.Serialization;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Data;
 // create a datatable with two columns [c1] and [c2]
 var dt = new System.Data.DataTable("MyTable");

 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("c1", typeof(System.Int32)));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("c2", typeof(System.String)));



 //create a new and populate it
 var dr = dt.NewRow();
 dr["c1"] = 1;
 //dr["c2"]="hello"; //purposely commented out, if not, there is NO error

 dt.Rows.Add(dr);

 var s = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(object[]));
 var mem = new MemoryStream();

// the following line will report error
 s.WriteObject(mem, dt.Rows[0].ItemArray);
// other lines ... which have nothing to do with this question
```

If I do not populate column [c2], it means there is DBNull value in this data row, then I will encounter error when trying to run **s.WriteObject()**.

Error:

> Type 'System.DBNull' with data contract name
>   'DBNull:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is not
>   expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using
>   DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the
>   list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.

But according to MS document "[Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)"

> The DBNull type is treated in a special way. It is a singleton type,
>   and upon deserialization the deserializer respects the singleton
>   constraint and points all DBNull references to the singleton instance.
>   Because **DBNull is a serializable type**, it demands
>   SerializationFormatter permission.

DBNull seems to be a supported type, and I am really confused here. 
Could any guru share a few lights please? such as what should I do?

I know I can scan all table rows and find if a column value equals DBNull.Value, if so, I set an empty string or something for this column, but this is not what I want because this will "tamper" the DataTable values.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add DBNull to the `knownTypes` list

```
var s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(object[]), new [] { typeof(DBNull) });
```